# TouchableOpacity in ListView requires 2 clicks for onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a TextInput that will render a ListView prompting text to AutoComplete however the TouchableOpacity requires 2 clicks to trigger (first to dismiss the keyboard)

Adding `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` to the `ListView` does **not** fix the problem.

Code:

```
render() {
    const { selected, searched } = this.state;
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={this.searchedText}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                onBlur={this.blurInput}
            />
            <ListView
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
                style={styles.autoCompleteListView}
                dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(searched)}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

...

```
renderRow = (rowData) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this._onPressRow.bind(this, rowData)}
    >
        <Text>{ rowData }</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Comment: Are there any other higher level scrollviews that could be wrapping that component? If so then you might have to add the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` value to those as well. Just a thought.

Comment: This actually all takes place within a FlatList - I will try

Comment: @ageoff That did the trick - you can submit as an answer and will select it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10138#issuecomment-304344283

All nested components need the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` property